# How to do convolution matrix operation in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to do [convolution matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) operation using numpy?

The [`numpy.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) only operates on 1D arrays, so this is not the solution.

I rather want to avoid using scipy, since it appears to be more difficult getting installed on Windows.

Comment: If you have a difficulty installing scipy in windows, use this whl file. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Answer (score 15):

You have scipy's [ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/ndimage.html) which allows you to perform N-dimensional convolution with [convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html):

```
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
convolve(data, kernel)
```

I know that you said that you want to avoid scipy... but I would advise against it. Scipy is great in so many ways. If you want to install it on windows, try [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which already comes with scipy installed.

Anaconda is a multiplatform python distribution that comes with all the essential libraries (including a lot of scientific computing libraries) preinstalled, and tools like `pip` or `conda` to install new ones. And no, they don't pay me to advertise it :/ but makes your multiplatform life much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the SciPy approach is less viable, since what I develop is to be used by others, so I would much prefer an easy way to install any prerequisites, and `pip install [package]` is a well known approach that is reasonable to require people to use, but installing something like Anaconda Distribution is another ball game.

Comment: @EquipDev Scipy is considered one of the core python packages. Maybe python is not the language for you. Using python for data analysis without scipy/numpy is like using matlab without toolboxes.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend using [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) for this purpose. However in principle you can almost directly use the "pseudo-code" on the [wiki-article on kernel convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) to create your own function...

```
ks = (kl-1)/2 ## kernels usually square with odd number of rows/columns
kl = len(kernel)
imx = len(matrix)
imy = len(matrix[0])
for i in range(imx):
  for j in range(imy):
    acc = 0
    for ki in range(kl): ##kernel is the matrix to be used
      for kj in range(kl):
        if 0 <= i-ks <= kl: ## make sure you don't get out of bound error
          acc = acc + (matrix[i-ks+ki][j-ks+kj] * kernel[ki][kj]) 
  matrix[i][j] = acc
```

this should in principle do the trick (but I have not yet tested it...)

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I used the example on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution) and extrapolated it for every element in the matrix:

```py
def image_convolution(matrix, kernel):
    # assuming kernel is symmetric and odd
    k_size = len(kernel)
    m_height, m_width = matrix.shape
    padded = np.pad(matrix, (k_size-1, k_size-1))
    
    # iterates through matrix, applies kernel, and sums
    output = []
    for i in range(m_height):
        for j in range(m_width):
            output.append(np.sum(padded[i:k_size+i, j:k_size+j]*kernel))

    output=np.array(output).reshape((m_height, m_width))
    return output
```

`padded[i:k_size+i, j:k_size+j]` is a slice of the array the same size as the kernel.

Hope this is clear and helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate numpy way to perform using matrix adds instead of cells reduces the looping.

```
def zConv(m,K):
#input assumed to be numpy arrays Kr<=mrow, Kc<=mcol, Kernal odd
#edges wrap Top/Bottom, Left/Right
#Zero Pad m by kr,kc if no wrap desired
  mc=m*0
  Kr,Kc= K.shape
  kr=Kr//2 #kernel center
  kc=Kc//2
  for dr in range(-kr,kr+1):
    mr=np.roll(m,dr,axis=0)
    for dc in range(-kc,kc+1):
      mrc=np.roll(mr,dc,axis=1)
      mc=mc+K[dr+kr,dc+kc]*mrc
  return mc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel is **not symmetric** (adjusted from the other answers):

```
def image_convolution(matrix, kernel):
    # kernel can be asymmetric but still needs to be odd
    k_height, k_width = kernel.shape
    m_height, m_width = matrix.shape
    k_size = max(k_height, k_width)
    padded = np.pad(matrix, (int(k_size/2), int(k_size/2)))

    if k_size > 1:
        if k_height == 1:
            padded = padded[1:-1,:]
        elif k_width == 1:
            padded = padded[:,1:-1]

    # iterates through matrix, applies kernel, and sums
    output = []
    for i in range(m_height):
        for j in range(m_width):
            between = padded[i:k_height+i, j:k_width+j]*kernel
            output.append(np.sum(between))

    output=np.array(output).reshape((m_height, m_width))
    return output
```