# Image denoising - Performing a task on each element of image matrix

Tags: python, image-processing, noise-reduction

I have been doing image processing lately and I chose Python to be my implementation language.

#### The Issue

I have two sets of matrices, one being my data matrix (that holds the image's pixel-wise values) and the other is kernel matrix. My requirement is to run over each element of the data matrix (excluding the edges) and calculate the certain value (by using kernel matrix) and replace the original value in data matrix with the calculated value.

#### Explanation

I have to replace each element with the sum of all the neighbors multiplied by the element in kernel matrix.
i.e., `d[i][j] = d[i-1][j-1] * k[0][0] + d[i][j-1] * k[0][1]....+ d[i+1][j+1] * k[1][1]` considering k to be a 3 x 3 matrix.

#### My code snippet

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
kernelMat = [[0, 1, 0], [1, -4, 1], [0, 1, 0]]

rowCount = len(data)
colCount = len(data[0])

for i in range(1, rowCount-1):
    for j in range(1, colCount-1):
        sum = 0
        for x in range(0, 3):
            for y in range(0, 3):
                sum = sum + data[i+x-1][j+y-1] * kernelMat[x][y]
        data[i][j] = sum


Expected output: [[1, 2, 3, 4],
            [5, 0, 0, 8],
            [9, 0, 0, 12],
            [13, 14, 15, 16]] but returning different set of values.
```

**Where I am going wrong?** I am new to programming, so pardon me if the question is silly.

Comment: Probably, you might be interested in this: [How to make a new filter and apply it on an image using cv2 in python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685757/how-to-make-a-new-filter-and-apply-it-on-an-image-using-cv2-in-python2-7) or [How to do convolution matrix operation in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373521/how-to-do-convolution-matrix-operation-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get expected output you just need to change the following line:

```
sum = sum + data[i+x-1][j+y-1] * kernelMat[x][y]
```

to:

```
sum = data[i+x-1][j+y-1] * kernelMat[x][y]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I am looking for :) 

But I am still confused on how the sum is cumulative here, would be grateful if you can spare some time on explaining it. :)